# Get list of files that match/don't match a query in Windows

Tags: windows, batch, file-search

I have a directory tree that contains ~150 files with a specific extension (`.php`) organized into different folders. Some of these files are marked on line 2 to indicate a certain status. I know that this mark is always on line 2, and it always follows a specific format.

What I'm looking for is something (a command, a script, a program) that can search the directory for this mark and give me output like this, but in an easy-to-manipulate format:

[image: example output]

An ideal solution would be one that can provide a list of ALL the `.php` files, with line 2 of the file next to the filename. The list above does this for matched files only.

I've tried using `find` in a `for` loop:

```
for %f in (*.php) do find "Oracle Status" %f
```

But this only searches the current directory, and doesn't format it in a friendly way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're alright with using PowerShell, this script ought to do the job:

```
Get-ChildItem *.php -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
 $lines = Get-Content $_ -TotalCount 2
 If ($lines.Length -GT 1 -And $lines[1].Length -GT 1 -And $lines[1].Contains('Oracle Status:')) {
  New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Prop @{'FilePath' = $_.FullName; 'StatusLine' = $lines[1]}
 }
}
```

It produces output that looks like this in the console:

[image: results]

<sup>The version shown here searched for `.txt` files with a `Status:` line, but the one pasted above does what you want.</sup>

Save the script as a `.ps1` file, e.g. `phpstatus.ps1`. If you've never run a PowerShell script before, you'll need to run this command once to allow the execution of scripts:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser
```

Once that's done, you can invoke the script from a PowerShell prompt by typing `.\` followed by its name, e.g. `.\phpstatus.ps1`. (Tab completion works.) Since the output is a collection of PowerShell objects, you can use standard PowerShell data management commands on them.

Comment: This is fantastic! I ended up making several tweaks to fit my needs (add items with status of "Untouched" if line 2 does not match, export to CSV, trim file path, sort, etc.), but you pushed me in the right direction! I suddenly love PowerShell. It's so underappreciated. <3